# Minecraft server switched from wired to a wireless access point, cant connect to it outside of LAN anymore

Tags: port-forwarding, wireless-access-point, pfsense, minecraft

I was running a Minecraft server for a buddy off my router and it was working fine, everyone could connect to it with no problems. I recently got a wireless access point for my network and while I have the server connected to that it can't be connected to at all besides using LAN now. I have a PC running PFSense as my router and a TP-Link eap225 access point. My PC running the server is not close enough to be wired anymore so I have to go wireless. I know the port forwarding works when wired but not when I'm using the access point. Everything is also on the same subnet so I don't think the problem is there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should verify you have updated your port forwarding rules.  When you changed from wired to wireless, the IP address for your device, was likely changed unless you were using a static assignment.

Comment: My local IP doesn't appear to have changed at all. This is my first time using a wireless access point, is there a chance I missed a setting on that end or is it most definitely on the routers side?

Comment: Repeat the entire process, you originally performed to forward the port, when the device was using a LAN adapter.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either, I decided to test with an older Linksys router I still have. Port forwarding on that using wifi worked perfectly. I connected the access point and made sure the port forwarding information was still correct and still had the same problem.